# Hasura quickstart hello-react not running

Tags: reactjs, hasura

I cloned a `hello-react app` from the **Hasura Hub**, deployed it but it is not running.

I get  a message saying-

**This typically happens when there is a port configuration error. 
    Check that the value of `service.spec.ports.targetPort` in

    `microservices/ui/k8s.yaml` is the port where your microservice is running.**

In the **k8s.yaml** file the port no. for targetPort is **8080**

On running hasura `ms logs -n user ui` the `react scripts start` and says

> starting the development server

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Hasura but if it has to match with the port where your React app is running, then port configuration must be 3000 since CRA dev server runs on this port.